# $a_{n+1}=\ln\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, logarithms, recursion

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of strictly positive numbers defined by the recursion $$a_{n+1}=\ln\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ The problem asks to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\bigg)e^{a_n}$$
What I managed to do is to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$, which is easy to see because $(a_n)_{n\ge2}$ is strictly increasing and we can thus show by contradiction that $(a_n)_n$ cannot have a finite limit. One would do that by adding $\ln\frac{1}{n}$ in the recursion formula and by taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in the whole equation to get $$l-\infty=\ln l$$, where $l$ is the supposed limit. This however would only be possible for $l=0$ or $l=\infty$, but because of the properties of our sequence the only left option is $l=\infty$.

I know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$$, so the indeterminate form of the original limit would be $0\cdot\infty$, but I have no idea how to prove it. I tried with the Stolz–Cesàro theorem but no luck.

I'm kind of new to this type of mathematics and got this problem at a math contest, destroyed me. I'd prefer an elementary solution, regarding the context. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why is $a_n$ increasing?

Comment: To the OP: it is incorrect that a strictly increasing sequence cannot have a finite limit—consider $a_n=1-\frac1n$ for example.

Comment: @GregMartin I agree with you on the general case. However, a monotone sequence does have a limit, whether it is finite or not. Here, the limit is infinity, and I think I proved it.

Comment: @Neox I don't think $a_n$ is monotone, but I do think the limit must be infinite. The reasoning is this: for $\sum a_n$ converge, we must have $\lim a_n = 0$, which is only possible if $\sum a_n \rightarrow 1$ but since we must have $a_1 >1$ and all other terms must be positive, we cannot have $\sum a_n \rightarrow 1$, therefore it must go to infinity.

Comment: @hellofriends $\text{sgn}(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})=\text{sgn}\bigg(\ln\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k-\ln\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\bigg)=\text{sgn}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\bigg)=\text{sgn}(a_{n+1})=1$

Comment: I even made a C++ program to calculate the first 100000 values and it seems like it is indeed increasing. I don't know how accurate that is, but I could get to $≈14.0765$ for $a_1=2$. The sequence increases, but very slowly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We observe that for $n\ge2$,
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n &= \ln\sum_{k=1}^n a_k - \ln\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \\
&= \ln \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \bigg/ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \biggr) \\
&= \ln \biggl( 1 + a_n \bigg/ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \biggr) = \ln\Bigl(1+\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}} \Bigr).
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
\biggl(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\biggr)e^{a_n} = \frac{e^{a_n}}{a_n} (a_{n+1}-a_n) = \frac{e^{a_n}}{a_n}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}} \Bigr) = \frac{\ln(1+t_n)}{t_n}
$$
where we have set $t_n = \dfrac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}$. Given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$, we deduce that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} t_n=0$ and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\biggr)e^{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+t_n)}{t_n} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}x = 1
$$
by l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Finally, thanks!